# Divide points on a plane with a line

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have N green points and M red points (no three of them are colinear). I want to tell if it is possible to divide those points with a line in such a way so all green points are on one side and all red points on the other side. If there is such line I would like to find the equation of it. The line cannot pass through those points. What is the fastest algorithm to solve this problem? This is not a homework assignment, just a problem I've recently thought about.

Answer (score 4):

Build [convex hulls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) for both sets. If they intersect, there is no such dividing line

[Citation:](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/0070482926/221825/42ConvexSetsConvexHullsandLinearSeparability.pdf)

> Two pattern sets Xi and Xj are said to be linearly separable if their
>   convex hulls are disjoint

When hulls are disjoint, line [might be found](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.155.5671&rep=rep1&type=pdf) with [rotating calipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers)

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly what [SVMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) do. More specifically, a SVM would find the line that is further from both sets of points, if they happen to be [linearly separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability); otherwise, the algorithm can be tuned to find some kind of "best-effort" solution.

There are plenty of sources where you can read about SVMs in more detail, but basically you would need to use a linear kernel. As an example, here is [the SVM implementation in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html), with some images.

Answer (score 0):

Use (single layer) `perceptron` to learn a `separating hyperplane` (a straight line in 2-dimensions), by posing the problem as a binary classification problem.

If two sets of points are `linearly separable`, then one such hyperplane exists, the perceptron algorithm is guaranteed to converge and solution will give you the `hyperplane` (a straight line in 2-dimensions) separating the two classes (green and blue).

In case the solution does not exist, the algorithm will not converge and we can stop after a finite number of iterations.

In either of the cases, after the algorithm stops (either with convergence or beyond maximum iterations), we can check whether all the points on the either sides of the output line are monochromatic (i.e., one side contains only red, another side contains only green points), if so, then return the equation of the line, otherwise output no such line exists.

We can use `perceptron pocket algorithm` too rather than using the naive implementation, but for our objective the naive implementation will also work (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron).